# Is there a more efficient/clean approach to an eval(parse(paste0( set up?

Tags: r, get, eval

Sometimes I have code which references a specific dataset based on some variable ID. I have then been creating lines of code using `paste0`, and then `eval(parse(...))` that line to execute the code. This seems to be getting sloppy as the length of the code increases. Are there any cleaner ways to have dynamic data reference?

Example:

```
dataset <- "dataRef"

execute <- paste0("data.frame(", dataset, "$column1, ", dataset, "$column2)")
eval(parse(execute))
```

But now imagine a scenario where dataRef would be called for 1000 lines of code, and sometimes needs to be changed to dataRef2 or dataRefX.

Comment: Try using a better data structure, such as a `list`.

Comment: Is this what you want:  `dataset <- "iris"; get(dataset)[c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]`

Comment: What -- nobody's mentioned `fortune(106)` yet?   Ok, srsly, Grothendieck's comment is one of two typical ways to deal with this. The other is `do.call` .

Comment: Grothendieck, this is what I am looking for thank you. If you add as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

Combining the comments of Jack Maney and G.Grothendieck:

It is better to store your data frames that you want to access by a variable in a list.  The list can be created from a vector of names using `get`:

```
mynames <- c('dataRef','dataRef2','dataRefX')
# or mynames <- paste0( 'dataRef', 1:10 )
mydfs <- lapply( mynames, get )
```

Then your example becomes:

```
dataset <- 'dataRef'
mydfs[[dataset]][,c('column1','column2')]
```

Or you can process them all at once using `lapply`, `sapply`, or a loop:

```
mydfs2 <- lapply( mydfs, function(x) x[,c('column1','column2')] )
```

Answer (score 3):

@G.Grothendieck has shown you how to use `get` and `[` to elevate a character value and return the value of a named object and then reference named elements within that object. I don't know what your code was intended to accomplish since the result of executing htat code would be to deliver values to the console, but they would not have been assigned to a name and would have been garbage collected. If you wanted to use three character values: objname, colname1 and colname2 and those columns equal to an object named after a fourth character value.

```
 newname <- "newdf"

 assign( newname, get(dataset)[ c(colname1, colname2) ]
```

The lesson to learn is `assign` and `get` are capable of taking character  character values and and accessing or creating named objects which can be either data objects or functions. Carl_Witthoft mentions do.call which can construct function calls from character values.

```
do.call("data.frame", setNames(list( dfrm$x,  dfrm$y), c('x2','y2') )

 do.call("mean", dfrm[1]) 
# second argument must be a list of arguments to `mean`
```